# Forwarded emails with attachments showing as MIME gibberish

Tags: email

Sometimes, when forwarding emails that have attachments, the recipient receives the email as plain-text base64 MIME. For example, the email is received as:

```
> MIME-Version: 1.0 
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--_com.android.email_209062387602790"
> 
> ----_com.android.email_209062387602790 
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
> 
> VGhlc2UgZ3V5cyBhcmUg... 
> ...(more base64 code)... 
> ...wKQmxhbmNhCsKgCgo=
```

It is maddening because this is happening for multiple email accounts on different servers, and on at least two devices.

Any chance there's help out there?

Comment: Have you tried using third-party email clients?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it is a bug that doesn't have a fix. That's what I understand from the 4/17/17 posted here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36907768

Also, no idea if this will work but it might be worth a try: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2079469